# How to get the nested/inner array values of mongodb in laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.1

I'm using mongodb in laravel 5.1 and I had the following database structure for states colection:

```
{
"state_name": "XXXXX",
"districts": [
            {
              "district_id": "1",
              "district_name": "AAAA"
            },
            {
               "district_id": "2",
               "district_name": "BBBBB"
            },
            {
                "district_id": "3",
                "district_name": "CCCC"
            },
  ]}
```

I need to get the districts as list and set in laravel select tag. How can I write query to fetch the inner array records as lists and set in laravel select tag?
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: db.bios.find( { contribs: "UNIX" } )

Comment: This is mongodb query. How can we write in laravel query?